# Will your undergrad GPA affect your graduate GPA in US?

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, gpa

Will your undergrad GPA affect your graduate GPA in US?

Comment: These GPAs are separate and they will not affect each other. As far as I know, this is true not only in US, but also in other countries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the two GPAs are separate.

Comment: This is not always true. But it is certainly always true if you attend a different school than where you did your undergrad. If you attend the same school, and you took grad coursework while completing the undergrad degree, depending on your schools policies, your grad GPA may include the grades from those courses. This is a rare situation to be in though.

Comment: @WetLabStudent I think this is the first time I've seen a comment that was substantially longer than the question and its answer combined!

Comment: @WetLabStudent, I was in that situation, and the grad class I took in my last undergrad semester *did not* count towards my undergrad GPA. I reserved that course's credit for grad school. My university only allowed the course to count towards one degree and, therefore, one GPA. I doubt any university allows the course to count twice.

Comment: @BillBarth which is why I said "depending on your school's policies." Unless you have verified this is how it works at every school, the qualification is important. I know of at least one school that does not count graduate class grades to your undergrad GPA, so in that case, they wouldn't be counting it twice if they counted it towards your grad GPA.

Comment: Unless you know of a university that allows you to count it as both grad and undergrad credit, I believe the effect on GPAs is the same.